# My mentor is advising me to "not worry about the cost"?

Tags: research-undergraduate, soft-money

In my school,  we have a program that allows students to do research as an undergrad with a mentor.  Not uncommon. Naturally,  as a participant,  this is my first dive into the world of research.
I am choosing to do research on high power lasers.

The school gives us a 3 figure budget,  but when my mentor heard of the laser being 5 figures, she told me "don't worry about it." And mentioned that she has something, but i didn't quite hear what she said. She kept putting emphasis on keeping on going "don't let the cost stop you", etc.

Is this common?  Should i apply for a grant? I'm not sure anything 5 figures is worth undergrad research. Is this generally the case?

Comment: The "something" she mentioned having that you didn't hear is probably a serious grant. And it is probably 6 or even 7 figures.

Comment: @LyndonWhite i still don't feel comfortable taking from that pool.  Is this common?

Comment: @tuskiomi not uncommon. Could the laser be a part that might still be used after you are done and gone (or stay for a PhD)?

Comment: @tuskiomi yes that's common. And also if it's really a laser then it will also be available for others (or other projects) to use.

Comment: Why are you not asking your mentor to explain this ?  They (and they alone) *know* what they meant.

Comment: I suspect your mentor may have had their eye on this equipment for some time, and the fact that you've given them demand for it, it will further bolster their case for purchasing it using extra grant money or general laboratory funding. Professors like new toys to play with.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your mentor, or prospective mentor, is telling you not to worry about the cost. Presumably, they know what they are talking about and have funding that can cover the costs. A $50,000, I am assuming US, laser could be easily covered by a large NSF/NIH type grant or start up funds. If it is a piece of equipment that the mentor needs for their lab and will use in the future, then it is no big deal. You are not taking money out of anyone's pocket. That said, you should realize that you will not be able to keep the laser at the end and it will likely stay in your mentor's lab.

Comment: I went in with the thought that any items bought with non -stipend money weren't mine to have, anyways. Goes to show how much i still have to learn.

Comment: @tuskiomi: This seems like a good opportunity to talk to your mentor and get clarification as to how the laser will be paid for, and what you will need to do as part of the process.  That's how you learn how these things work!

Answer (score 0):

First since you didn't quite hear what she said, you should ask what it was that she said that you missed.

If she says she "has something", ask what that is--does she already have an equivalent laser you can use? Is she planning to buy one? Obviously you're not going to stretch a 3 figure budget to 5 figures by magic.

You can still make progress on your project in the mean time by writing out what you plan to do in more detail, getting more citations for your write-up etc. Once you've done that, you can tell her you're ready to use the 5-figure laser and actually do the experiment--you just need access to one. In other words: bring the future events she's telling you not to worry about into the present so that they're something you need help doing immediately rather than some future thing you're uncertain about that she can put off or explain later.

Comment: No, clarify the situation first. It would be a total waste of time to do all that preparatory work and only then find out that you'd misunderstood and there is no laser.

Comment: Right. That's what I said. Further prep work is if she refuses to communicate further details. At that point you just have to trust her. (or don't. that's also an option.)